# Using GitHub list-issues-for-a-repository API

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v3

When you go to GitHub, under Issues, it pulls up all the open issues as an HTML page. We'd like to implement a dashboard showing all the issues in a repository, grouped by labels, including those issues which are not correctly labelled.

This is the corresponding [list-issues-for-a-repository API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues-for-a-repository).

While I was initially using jQuery and Javascript, am now using PHP for a proof-of-concept because its built-in session handling lets me use the same page to login, have GitHub authenticate & callback, and continue. But it doesn't matter to me, any language is okay.

I've managed to get access to the GitHub API via OAUTH2, but when I get the list of repositories via `https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}/repos` it comes up as an empty array.

Because the `/orgs/{org}/repos` API returns an empty array, of course the corresponding `/repos/{org}/{repo}/issues` API will return an error.

**Edit**: See [this followup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58964401) for a solution! Glad I finally got it working!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a rest API. You need to call some endpoints using an Http request. 
I don't know what language you are trying to use so I can't give you a good example on how to acheive this. 
If you don't know which language to use yet, use [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to create REST API call to the github API.

Let's say you want to retreive the issues of the [microsoft's typescript repo](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript), You would need to call this API endpoint :

```
https://api.github.com/repos/microsoft/typescript/issues
```

Notice here that i have replace the `:owner` and `:repo` value of documentation for the one i'm trying to get.

You can then pass some parameters to the call to filter your data, for example, the API label.

```
https://api.github.com/repos/microsoft/typescript/issues?labels=API
```

This will only return issues that are labelled as `API`.

This is the basics of how to use an API.

Comment: Thank you. That got me part way there. It's telling me `{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues-for-a-repository"
}`, but I read up and that's apparently the standard response when trying to access private repos, so researching on OAuth, etc. FWIW, using JavaScript under jQuery framework.

Comment: There probably is, but at this point, i cannot teach you how oauth works. There is plenty of tutorial online. I must say, don't take this the wrong way, but this is quite a big project for someone with your knownledge of APIs. I just want to make sure you know what you are getting into @YiminRong

Comment: Thank you. I've gotten OAUTH2 to work, but it's not returning expected information. Please see edit in issue.

Comment: Hi @Nicolas I got stuck in a scenario where i need to filter only the user-generated issues. This is the API link of a repository issue list https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/issues
I want to filter only the user-generated issue but it also included the issue created by the "renovate[bot]". Please help me how can I do this?

Comment: @SalmanAhmad-MeanDeveloper The only filter, we seams to be able to use is `filter` with the parameter `all`. This will returns all the issues for a given repo. You can then filter out the one that have "renovate[bot]" as their property `user.login`, in whatever language you are using.

Comment: @Nicolas Thanks man I was thinking the same and I figure it out by filtering the list using user.type !== 'Bot'. Actually, I was looking at the solution from the API filter but unfortunately, no options are there.

Comment: @SalmanAhmad-MeanDeveloper A solution directly on the API side would be ideal, but it doesn't look like there is, no. Good luck with your project !

Answer (score 5):

You can use jQuery Ajax to access the Github API and add a basic authentication header to authenticate (see [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/)), an example is shown below, this will pull the issues for a given repo and show the first 10 in an alert window.

See the documentation on pulling issues here: https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/ to see which parameters you can use to filter, sort etc.

For example you can get all issues labelled 'bug' using:

```
/issues?labels=bug
```

This can include multiple labels, e.g.

```
/issues?labels=enhancement,nicetohave
```

You could easily modify to list in a table etc.

```
const username = 'github_username'; // Set your username here
const password = 'github_password'; // Set your password here
const repoPath = "organization/repo" // Set your Repo path e.g. microsoft/typescript here

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: `https://api.github.com/repos/${repoPath}/issues`,
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        // Send basic authentication header.
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("Response:", response);
            alert(`${repoPath} issue list (first 10):\n - ` + response.slice(0,10).map(issue => issue.title).join("\n - "))
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert("error: " + JSON.stringify(xhr));
        }
    });
});
```

Below is a snippet listing issues for a (public) repo using jQuery and the Github API:

(Note we don't add an authentication header here!)

```js
const repoPath = "leachim6/hello-world" // 

$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: `https://api.github.com/repos/${repoPath}/issues`,
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (response) {
        tbody = "";
        response.forEach(issue => {
            tbody += `<tr><td>${issue.number}</td><td>${issue.title}</td><td>${issue.created_at}</td><td>${issue.state}</td></tr>`;
        });
        $('#output-element').html(tbody);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        alert("error: " + JSON.stringify(xhr));
    }
});
});
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Issue Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body style="margin:50px;padding:25px">
<h3>Issues in Repo</h3>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Issue #</th>
        <th scope="col">Title</th>
        <th scope="col">Created</th>
        <th scope="col">State</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="output-element">
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll look at this ASAP. I'm not getting the expected results using OAUTH2, and I noticed one API `https://api.github.com/authorizations` indicated that it could be accessed only with basic authorization: `stdClass Object
(
    [message] => This API can only be accessed with username and password Basic Auth
    [documentation_url] => https://developer.github.com/v3
)`. So maybe this will work.

Comment: The basic authentication works for me,  using my github credentials. If you wish to access a public repo you can comment out the beforeSend section!

Comment: Hi @TerryLennox
I got stuck in a scenario where I need to filter only the user-generated issues. This is the API link of a repository issue list https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular/issues I want to filter only the user-generated issue but it also included the issue created by the "renovate[bot]". Please help me how can I do this?

Comment: Maybe an Array.filter will work for the user name once the issues are retrieved from the api?

Comment: @TerryLennox Thanks man I was thinking the same and I figure it out by filtering the list using user.type !== 'Bot'. Actually, I was looking at the solution from the API filter.